# How to change full calendar views

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and currently its showing monthly view [image].

I am using following code to initialize the full calendar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2014-06-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2014-06-07',
                    end: '2014-06-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2014-06-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2014-06-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2014-06-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2014-06-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2014-06-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2014-06-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2014-06-28'
                }
            ]
        });

    });
```

But i want to change the view like this [image]

Please suggest how to achieve this in fullcalendar ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you include your code for initializing the calendar?

Answer (score 2):

To set the initial view, add the 'defaultView' property to your calendar initialization code.  Possible view types are:month (default), basicWeek, basicDay, agendaWeek and agendaDay.  I think the one that most closely approximates your screen shot is agendaWeek.  View examples of each type [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/).

**Initial Load Example:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
        editable: true,
....the rest of your code here
```

**Event Driven Example:**
To change the view based on some event, such as a button click, call the controls 'changeView' method and pass it the name of the view you'd like to see.

> $('#buttonName').click(function () {
>   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month'); });

Comment: Thanks for the answer....Actually i am looking for resource view in the left of the calendar for each row. Any suggestion how can we achieve this. I searched on google but did not find any solution.